# iOS Webview only allows TextMode="MultiLine" input other TextMode's don't work?

Tags: asp.net, webview, xamarin.ios

When I try to use TextMode="Number" and you tap that field on an iOS device, the keyboard does not show up.

I've tested a few other TextMode options as well but only "MultiLine" seems to work. Other modes do not bring up the keyboard for that specific field.

Here's the code below for where I need it to pop up a number keyboard only on the devices. Android has no issues.

```
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
             runat="server" 
             ControlToValidate="TxtCell" ErrorMessage="Please supply your 
             contact number." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
             ViewStateMode="Disabled"
             Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValidNumber" runat="server" 
             ControlToValidate="TxtCell"
             ErrorMessage="Please supply a valid NUMBER!" 
             ValidationGroup="valGroup" ForeColor="Red"
             ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{10}$" />

            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCell" runat="server" CssClass="TxtBox" 
             MaxLength="11" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="Contact 
             Number" type="number"></asp:TextBox>
```